# Linux JAVA in path but permissions denied

Tags: java, path, permissions, intel-edison

Im trying to get JAVA enabled on Intel Edison which uses Yocto (Linux), the problem is that after extracting the zip, im able to check the version, and when putting it into the path, im not able to access java at all due permissions.

Specifically im trying to follow this [tutorial](https://communities.intel.com/message/257302#257302) but i get "stuck" at the

```
. .profile
```

since next step

```
java -version
```

throws same issue as pasted below, permissions denied or as earlier, java was not found.

Heres a quick overview of output:

```
root@dedsec1:~/java/jdk1.7.0_67/bin# ./java -version
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
root@dedsec1:~/java/jdk1.7.0_67/bin# cd
root@dedsec1:~# echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/root/bin:/home/root/java/jdk1.7.0_67/bin:/home/root/java/jdk1.7.0_67/bin
root@dedsec1:~# ./java -version
-sh: ./java: Permission denied
root@dedsec1:~#
```

What the hell am i missing ?  I have set chmod -x on java but it doesnt seem to affect it.

Comment: offtopic. Do not do normal work under root account.

Comment: Try this root@dedsec1:~# java -version not root@dedsec1:~# ./java -version

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/java
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javac
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javaws
sudo chown -R root:root /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0
```

Comment: Unfortunately sudo nor such are available, no idea what yocto has for options :/

Comment: Tho I correct myself, running chmod a+x /root/bin/java did the trick and am able to call java now, what exactly is a ? I know x is executable.

Comment: @DanelK a+x mean's  add executable permissions to all users

Comment: Aaaand, the first line was the answer I needed after 3 days of searching! *Closes multiple open tabs and moves on happily*

Answer (score 2):

`root`'s home folder is not under "/home". Change this

```
/home/root/java/jdk1.7.0_67/bin:/home/root/java/jdk1.7.0_67/bin
```

to

```
/root/java/jdk1.7.0_67/bin
```

Also,

```
/home/root/bin
```

should probably be

```
/root/bin
```

For similar reasons. When writing a script you can use `$HOME` which will expand to wherever the user's home directory happens to be. So,

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/java/jdk1.7.0_67/bin"
```

**Edit**

I would not recommend that you link to `java` in `$HOME/bin`. Let's set a `JAVA_HOME` and move that to the front of the PATH like

```
export JAVA_HOME=$HOME/java/jdk1.7.0_67
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be logged in as Root

```
. .profile
```

If that doesn't work you can source your file.

```
source .profile
```

note that source is a synonym of '.' (period).

Comment: There is a space between the dots. *And* it is synonym for source.

Comment: When  doing ssh root@ip im asked root pass which i hopefullay am logged in as :S but the output for source .profile gave me this: http://pastebin.com/iqcCn1bm

Comment: just enter java -version without the ./

Comment: once your executable can be located on your Path, you no longer need ./

Comment: Yeah Ive figured that but it doesn't seem to find java at all