# Cannot edit .profile on Mac OS Catalina

Tags: java, linux, macos, jboss

I wanted to declare $JAVA_HOME in .profile in /etc folder for Mac. I gave it permission using `chmod 777 profile` still it doesn't let me edit it.

I am new to development in mac.

Following is the error I get

[image]

Comment: What error do you get? Which `.profile` are you trying to edit, the one associated with your user `/Users/${username}/.profile`, right?

Comment: @AlexSomai one in /etc.  Edited the question. there's no .profile in /Users/${username}/

Comment: You can create it if there isn't any `.profile` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to edit the `.profile` from your user, and not the one under `/etc` (to edit that one you need sudo rights, and even if you do edit it, most probably it won't be read correctly).

So, as a regular user (not sudo), open the one from your user. Using `open` (as in your screenshot, but I would rather choose `vim`). One of the below commands should work:

```
open ~/.profile
```

or

```
open /Users/${your-username}/.profile
```

I guess `${your-username}` is `divya`, so the complete path would be:

```
open /Users/divya/.profile
```

If you get an error saying `The File /.../.profile does not exist`, first create an empty one:

```
touch ~./profile
```

Add in the `.profile` file, the following line:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home
```

(make sure to use the Java version installed on your machine)

Then, for the changes to take place, either restart your terminal window, or type:

```
source ~/.profile
```

And to validate that you've set the `$JAVA_HOME` correctly:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Followed by:

```
java -version
```

Comment: Also one more doubt. I have been confused quite a lot. the path for java_home would it be 'export JAVA_HOME=`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home`' since the Home folder has bin?

Comment: It says permission denied for the given java path when I do  'source ~/.profile'

Comment: Hey, can you suggest to me about this last doubt? It will be a lifesaver for me. No more doubt after this I promise

Comment: Hmm ... this is new to me, as well. Try to close and re-open the terminal, and check if it outputs the `$JAVA_HOME` like that.

Comment: did echo $JAVA_HOME. Its empty

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686084/linux-java-in-path-but-permissions-denied .. but the last command did not work for chown stating such a group 'root' does not exist.

Comment: You can try just `sudo chown -R root`, without the `:group`. But I'm not sure if that will solve your problem.

Comment: No it did not help

Comment: Just tried again what I've posted in my answer, and it works in my case, no errors on the `source` command :/

Comment: And this is the JAVA_HOME I've set `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home`

Comment: :/ il give it a try again or search some more. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: Ok it worked. i had written  JAVA_HOME=`'/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home'`. I removed those quotes (the one with ~) and it worked.

Comment: Cool :) I'll update my answer to include that, for future readers.

Comment: Thank you for your help and time :)